# When calling BCrypt is get the error - Line 535: Cannot invoke clone() on the array type int[]

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, encryption, bcrypt

I am using the following code to generate an encrypted password:

```
class DuplicateHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<User> {
  public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
    Window.alert("RPC call failed.");
  }

  public void onSuccess(User result) {
    User u = result;
    if (u == null) {
      String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(passwordTextBoxEmail.getText(),
          BCrypt.gensalt());
      System.out.println("Hashed password lenth is: " + pw_hash.length());
      AsyncCallback<User> callback = new CreationHandler<User>();
      rpc.createUser(textBoxAccount.getText(), pw_hash, null, null, null,
          callback);
    } else {
      Window
          .alert("Username already in use. Please select another Username.");
    }
  }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Validating units:
[INFO] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Module org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker has been loaded
[ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Glyndwr/Eclipse/Workspace/AwardTracker/src/org/AwardTracker/client/BCrypt.java'
[ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Line 535: Cannot invoke clone() on the array type int[]
[ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Line 536: Cannot invoke clone() on the array type int[]
[ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Line 609: Cannot invoke clone() on the array type int[]
[ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Line 706: No source code is available for type java.security.SecureRandom; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] - Uncaught exception escaped

15:10:39.817 [ERROR] [org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker] Uncaught exception escaped

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot invoke clone() on the array type int[]

at org.AwardTracker.client.BCrypt.crypt_raw(BCrypt.java:609)
at org.AwardTracker.client.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:682)
at org.AwardTracker.client.CreateAccountView$1$DuplicateHandler.onSuccess(CreateAccountView.java:103)
at org.AwardTracker.client.CreateAccountView$1$DuplicateHandler.onSuccess(CreateAccountView.java:1)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As per the documentation I have included BCrypt.java and the single line to call BCypt and return a value. I have not modified BCrypt.java.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Comment: Given that it says "Unresolved compilation problem" presumably you can see this as a problem *before* you actually try to run it. It's almost never a good idea to try to run code while you've got compilation errors.

Comment: Hi Jon,I did not see any errors when compiling it in Eclipse and I did a new build on it. I will look to see if I can find something I missed.

Comment: You won't see the errors during the Java compilation, since this is a GWT-related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing in GWT, that is, I wanted to use BCrypt on the client side; unfortunately, the java.security package has not been ported to GWT, which is why you cannot use the java.security.SecureRandom class on the client side. One solution would be to port that class yourself. My decision was to use BCrypt on the server side, and to rely on secure sockets (SSL) to protect the passwords sent from the client to the server. The packages that have been made available on the client side in GWT can be found here: [JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation)

Comment: Hi Andy, I think porting the java.security.SecureRandom class may be a bit out of my league at this stage. I would prefer to do this on the client side. Is there any other package I can use? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi Andy, I have done some reading and apparently it is safer to do the security on the server side. Are you able to point me in the direstion of an easily implemented password encryption for server side? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: I'm using BCrypt on the server side ... it is great. But note that if you don't use HTTPS then it really isn't very secure.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you. I have added it to the server side and it works. Thank you very much for your help; greatly appreciated. Regards, Glyn